# Fourier transform on Laplace equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

We can solve some Laplace equations on the lectangular area by using Fourier transform. However many textbooks only introduce the cases when the area is given as a half plane or a strip.

; $y>0, -\infty<x<\infty $ or $ 0<y<\pi, -\infty<x<\infty$

I want to know if there is a similar mehod on a square area.

For the general case like
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0 \ \ \ \forall \ (x,y) \in (0,2\pi)^2$$
$$u(0,y)=f_1(y),\ u(2\pi,y)=f_2(y) \ \forall y \in [0,2\pi]$$
$$u(x,0)=g_1(x),\ u(x,2\pi)=g_2(x) \ \forall x \in [0,2\pi]$$

Or for the mixed case like

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0 \ \ \ \forall \ (x,y) \in (0,2\pi)^2$$
$$u(0,y)=u_x(0,y),\ u(2\pi,y)=f_2(y)\ \forall y \in [0,2\pi]$$
$$u(x,0)=g_1(x),\ u(x,2\pi)=g_2(x)\ \forall x \in [0,2\pi]$$

Any help will be appreicated.

Comment: Laplace's equation on a bounded region is typically solved through separation of variables leading to Fourier series solutions. [See for example section 3.3 here.](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~vvksrini/Fund-laplace.pdf)

Comment: I know that it is solved by the seperation of variables. What I want to know is if there is a direct way to apply the Fourier transform.